# My naked url can't be linked with a "www"

Tags: url, redirect, google-cloud-platform

**Issue:**

I have a naked url which works, but "www." + the naked url yields a 404 error. I'd like to point the www version to the naked version.

**Context:**

I have a serverless website, deployed on google cloud run.

I have a domain name registered through google domains, let's call it `foo.bar`.

Google cloud run provides two types of resource types for me to provide to google domains: `A` and `AAAA`, which are ipv4 and ipv6 addresses respectively.

I have added these `A` and `AAAA` records as custom records to google domains. With google domains, the hostname field is left blank, which is equivalent to `@`. From my understanding, this means that when someone types `foo.bar`, they get directed to these ipv4/ipv6 addresses. This works as intended.

But if I type `www.foo.bar`, I get a 404 error. As far as I know, `www.foo.bar` and `foo.bar` are not equivalent, and so there is no expectation that these two things should work unless explicitly instructed to. So I have tried two approaches to link these, as follows:

1. Added the `A` and `AAAA` resources, but specified `www` as the hostname, rather than blank. I would expect this to point `www.foo.bar` to the ipv4/ipv6 addresses too.
2. Added a `CNAME` resource, which specifies `www.foo.bar` as the hostname, and `foo.bar` as the data. I would expect this to redirect `www.foo.bar` to `foo.bar`, which points towards the ipv4/ipv6 addresses.

I would expect both of these to work equivalently, yet neither of them work. I feel like I am misunderstanding what is going on when managing these records, or that google domains is more opaque about what it is doing than I'd like.

Is my understanding of what should happen incorrect? And how can I properly set up the `www` extension?

Answer (score 1):

You must create Cloud Run custom domains for each hostname. One for **example.com** and another for **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**. You must also create the DNS resource records, which you mentioned that you did complete.

Comment: This fixed the issue.

For people with a similar issue:
I went to cloud run -> manage custom domains -> Add Mapping
I then selected the same domain, but specified a subdomain, which was `www`
This provided CNAME data, which I added to the custom records in google domains.